# How to use a variable after loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I get an element with Javascript as,

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
if(els[i].nodeValue == 'Something') {
var el = els[i];
break;
}
}

console.log(el);
```

How can I be sure that the loop has been finished before `console.log`?

Note that I cannot put `console.log` inside the loop. This is just a simple example, and I need `el` for further processing.

Comment: In that code, the `console.log` will be executed always after the loop finishes.

Comment: This loop is synchronous, `el` has the value at the end of the loop

Comment: You should define your variable `el` above the loop

Comment: What reason do you have to think that the loop won't finish first? (I imagine you are trying to do something with asynchronous code, but you need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, not one which does exactly what you say it should do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can I be sure that the loop has been finished before console.log?

Because you're looping using a for loop, which is a synchronous loop.

```
for (var i = 0, max = 1000000; i < max; i++) {

}

console.log('Finished');
```

Above, finished will **always** be executed after the for loop has finished it's last iteration.

In your example, you can be sure that your log will execute after the loop, because of what I've said above. What you can't be sure of is that your variable will be undefined or not.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {

    // If this does not get hit, your 'el' will be undefined.
    if(els[i].nodeValue == 'Something') {
        var el = els[i];
        break;
    }
}

console.log(el);
```

FYI (as an aside), you should look at [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in javascript, you declare your 'el' variable inside the IF statement, however there is no block-scoping with var, i.e. you could/should define the el variable underneath the els variable, to avoid confusion.

E.g.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

var el;

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {

    // If this does not get hit, your 'el' will be undefined.
    if(els[i].nodeValue == 'Something') {
        el = els[i];
        break;
    }
}

console.log(el);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the `el` vriable outside the loop.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var el;


for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
if(els[i].nodeValue == 'Something') {
el = els[i];
break;
}
}

console.log(el);
```

Comment: That makes no practical difference. `var` statements are hoisted to the top of the enclosing function (or global scope if they are outside of any function).